# Using Automapper to map viewmodel to domain model returns nulls in POST action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, automapper

I have a entity model that records some employee information.  I have a similar view model.

In my create action I create a new instance of the viewmodel and pass a few lists for dropdowns.

In my Create Post action I map using AutoMapper the returned view model to the entity model.

I am doing something wrong because the posted back data doesn't seem to contain any of the view model data.  It just contains nulls.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

*Controller*

```
   // GET: /TimeCreditEntries/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var Model = new TimeCreditEntryViewModel();  //Create a new viewmodel to hold the TimeCreditEntry
        Model.StationList = new SelectList(getStations(), "StationId", "Code");
        Model.AuthorisedEmployee = new SelectList(getEmployees(), "EmployeeId", "FullNameSurnameFirst");
        Model.AuthorisedPayment = new SelectList(getPaymentTypes(), "PaymentTypeId", "Code");
        return View(Model); //View is returned with model as parameter.
   }



    // POST: /TimeCreditEntries/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TimeCreditEntryId,RecordedDate,TimeCreditDate,ShiftId,StationId,AuthorisingEmployeeId,AuthorisedEmployeeId,ModifiedDate")] TimeCreditEntryViewModel timeCreditEntry)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<TimeCreditEntryViewModel, TimeCreditEntry>();
            db.TimeCreditEntries.Add(Mapper.Map<TimeCreditEntryViewModel, TimeCreditEntry> (timeCreditEntry));
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Register"); }
                                             ViewBag.AuthorisedEmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeId", "Title", timeCreditEntry.AuthorisedEmployeeId);
              ViewBag.AuthorisingEmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeId", "Title", timeCreditEntry.AuthorisingEmployeeId);
              ViewBag.ShiftId = new SelectList(db.Shifts, "ShiftId", "Code", timeCreditEntry.ShiftId);
        return View(timeCreditEntry);
    }
```

*View*

```
@model ATAS.Models.ViewModels.TimeCreditEntryViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Request to use time credit</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="AuthorisedEmployee">Who</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorisedEmployee, Model.AuthorisedEmployee, "Select Employee", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorisedEmployeeId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeCreditDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TimeCreditDate, new { @class = "datepicker", id = "vacation" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeCreditDate)
            </div>r
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="StationList">Where</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StationList, Model.StationList, "Choose Station", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Shift">Which</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Shift", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker()


    $("#Shift").prop("disabled", true);
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $("#StationList").change(function () {
        $("#Shift").empty();
        if ($("#StationList").val() != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetShiftsByStation")', // we are calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { selectedValue: $("#StationList").val() },
                // here we are get value of selected Station and passing same value as input to json method GetShifts.
                success: function (shiftList) {
                    // states contains the JSON formatted list
                    // of states passed from the controller
                    $("#Shift").append('<option value="' + null + '">' + "Choose shift" + '</option>');

                    $.each(shiftList, function (i, shift) {
                        $("#Shift").append('<option value="' + shift.Value + '">' + shift.Text + '</option>');
                        // here we are adding option for shifts
                        $("#Shift").prop("disabled", false);
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve shifts.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#Shift").empty();
            $("#Shift").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: There are numerous potential problems with your code. First, remove the `[Bind]` attribute - your using a view model which means that the view model should only ever contain the properties your need to display/edit. Next you dropdownlists need to bind to a value type property, not the `SelectList` itself - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AuthorisedEmployeeId, Model.AuthorisedEmployee)` - and I recommend changing the name to `AuthorisedEmployeeList` or similar to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thankyou - MVC is new to me.

Comment: Start by making those changes, but you really need to show your model in order to see what other issues you have. For example your `[Bind]` attribute suggests you have a property named `RecordedDate` but no where in you view do you have a form control for that property so nothing will be bound.